# Migrating mysql 5.7 DB to Amazon Aurora RDS - Options

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

We are attempting to migrate one of our DB's to Amazon Aurora. After extensive research, it seems that our options are limited. Because we are on 5.7, we are unable to use the "restore from s3" option as it's 5.6 only. Other than doing a dump or general restore is there any other viable option? Could we use Percona without using the "restore from s3" option?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this with the restore from s3 option or something similar. Hopefully, this functionality will be added to 5.7 soon. However, we have two methods that we tested.

1. Restore from dump
2. Replication

Restore from dump worked well, although time consuming. We are no prepping our AWS instance and using replication to move the data. This allows us a very short downtime.

Comment: Update: Replication was successful from Aurora to a non-AWS mysql 5.7 server. Setup is the same as replication from any other 5.7 to 5.7.